# JavaScript/jQuery and PHP Ajax force an error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to force an error state to return to an ajax request from a PHP script?

I am handling the success and error states in an ajax request and I want a way to force the error.  The error only seems to be triggered by xhttp error and I want to trigger this when a condition is not met at the server.  Its seems confusing to have to return success and have to actually put a flag in the response for an error

Answer (score 7):

You could approach this from two angles:

- Force an error to be thrown by outputting an HTTP header such as a 404 or 503.
- Force an error to be thrown based on certain condition of the resulting data.

**Force an error to be thrown by outputting an HTTP header such as a 404 or 503:**

PHP

```
<?php
if(User::Login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) { // Your logic here
  print 'Login successful!';
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
  print 'Bad user name / password';
}
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  'url': '/some/url',
  'type': 'POST',
  'data': {
    'username': 'someone@example.com',
    'password': 'rhd34h3h'
  },
  'success': function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('ERROR: ' + textStatus);
  }
});
```

**Force an error to be thrown based on certain condition of the resulting data:**

PHP

```
<?php
$return = array();
if(User::Login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) { // Your logic here
  $return['success'] = True;
  $return['message'] = 'Login successful!';
} else {
  $return['success'] = False;
  $return['message'] = 'Bad user name / password';
}
print json_encode($return);
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  'url': '/some/url',
  'type': 'POST',
  'dataType': 'json',
  'data': {
    'username': 'someone@example.com',
    'password': 'rhd34h3h'
  },
  'success': function(data) {
    if(data['success']) { // Successful login
      alert(data['message']);
    } else { // Login failed, call error()
      this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
    }
  },
  'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('ERROR: ' + textStatus);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to do this, for example:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
```

Comment: Also, the code could be any of a number of standard HTTP 'error' status codes in the 400-500 range: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error